# In Ruby, should we always use "&&", "||" instead of "and", "or" unless for special situations?

Tags: ruby, logical-operators

Is it true that in most cases, in Ruby, it is best to use `&&`, `||` instead of `and`, `or`, unless it is some special situations.

I think one of Ruby's design principles is to have least surprises as possible, so using `and`, or `or` actually have some surprises... such as `and` not having a higher precedence than `or`, while `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`.

So I think in most cases, use `&&`, `||`.  In know in some special situations, it may require using `and`, `or`, but I think if those are intermixed with `&&`, `||`, sooner or later it may create bugs when your coworkers who started in Ruby not so long ago need to edit your code.

Comment: the question is the title of the post

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512547/what-is-the-difference-between-perls-or-and-and-short-circuit-op

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Relying on `and` and `or` for boolean logic is a good way to introduce subtle bugs into your application.

They do have a place, though.  They are a safe and readable option when used as control flow operators.

```
redirect_to root_url and return
```

I basically felt the way you did until I read [this excellent blog post](http://avdi.org/devblog/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/).

Comment: Misunderstanding or misusing `and`, `or`, and `&&` and `||` is a problem in many languages. People assume (wrongly) that they are interchangable, ignoring the precedence of each. Like Raphomet says, not knowing when to use each one leads to subtle bugs. I agree that the best use of `and` and `or` is as a flow-control, leading to more readable code. Liberal use of `(` and `)` can go a long ways to avoid the problem too, though it can lead to code that looks like line noise... or Perl.

Answer (score 7):

The book 'The Ruby Programming Language' (David Flanagan & Yukihiro Matsumoto) gives two reasons to use 'and'.

- readability:

  `if x > 0 and y > 0 and not defined? d then
     d = Math.sqrt(x*x +y*y)
   end`
- make good use of the lower precedence:

  `if a = get_from_db(x) and b = get_from_db(y) then do_stuff_with_true_values(a, b) end`

(code adapted by me) The last one just wouldn't work with '&&'.

Personally, I use 'and' and 'or' combined with parentheses in case of doubt, for readability.-

Comment: +1 for "combined with parentheses"

Answer (score 2):

It's because `and`, `or` & `not` have lower precedence than `&&`, `||` and `!`.

Why? Because it stems from Perl.  [Larry Wall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall) being a linguist wanted the following to work:

```
open my $fh, "<", $filename or die $!;
```

If you replace the `or` with `||` then that statement would be parsed like this:

```
open my $fh, "<", ($filename || die $!);
```

Which is not good!

So for languages like Perl & Ruby where parenthesis are often optional then this was the solution. Otherwise you would need to write:

```
open( my $fh, "<", $filename ) || die $!;
```

See [perlop "Logical Not, And, or, Defined or, and Exclusive Or](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Not) && [Logical operators in Perl and Ruby](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2007/06/02/logical-operators-in-perl-and-ruby/) for the full shake down.

/I3az/