# Why || and or behaves differently in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [i = true and false in Ruby is true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802494/i-true-and-false-in-ruby-is-true)
>   [What is the difference between Perl's ( or, and ) and ( ||, && ) short-circuit operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512547/what-is-the-difference-between-perls-or-and-and-short-circuit-op)
>   [Ruby: difference between || and 'or'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/ruby-difference-between-and-or)

Is `||` same as `or` in Rails?

Case A:

```
 @year = params[:year] || Time.now.year
 Events.all(:conditions => ['year = ?', @year])
```

will produce the following SQL in `script/console`:

```
 SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE (year = 2000)
```

Case B:

```
 @year = params[:year] or Time.now.year
 Events.all(:conditions => ['year = ?', @year])
```

will produce the following SQL in `script/console`:

```
 SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE (year = NULL)
```

Comment: Same as the question [i = true and false in Ruby is true?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802494/i-true-and-false-in-ruby-is-true) except with `or` instead of `and`.

Comment: Duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826112/in-ruby-should-we-always-use-instead-of-and-or-unless-for-specia/3828955#3828955, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512547/what-is-the-difference-between-perls-or-and-and-short-circuit-op and probably many more.

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered in http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2083112/, http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1625946/, http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1426826/, http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1840488/, http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1434842/, http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2376369/, http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2802494/, http://StackOverflow.Com/q/372652/.

Comment: @Andrew can you suggest the keywords to search duplicates for this question? I am not sure how to make the search works for `||` and `or`.

Comment: I put it as another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938961/how-to-search-and-or-on-stackoverflow

Comment: @ohho: If you wrote a question with a title "Ruby and or operators", you get [Understanding the “||” OR operator in If conditionals in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554340/understanding-the-or-operator-in-if-conditionals-in-ruby)

Comment: @Andrew are you sure the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554340/understanding-the-or-operator-in-if-conditionals-in-ruby question talks about the difference between `||` and `or`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason that || and or behave differently is because of operator precedence.

Both || and && have higher precedence than the assignment operator and the assignment operator (=) has higher precedence than and/or

So your expressions will actually be evaluated as follows :-

`@year = params[:year] || Time.now.year`

is evaluated as

`@year = ( params[:year] || Time.now.year )`

and

`@year = params[:year] or Time.now.year`

is evaluated as

`( @year = params[:year] ) or Time.now.year`

If in doubt about precedence rules then use parentheses to make your meaning clear.

Answer (score 4):

Quote from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators:

> The binary "or" operator will return the logical disjunction of its two operands. It is the same as "||" but with a lower precedence.

```
a = nil
b = "foo"
c = a || b  # c is set to "foo" its the same as saying c = (a || b)
c = a or b  # c is set to nil   its the same as saying (c = a) || b which is not what you want.
```

So you `or` works as:

```
(@year = params[:year]) or Time.now.year
```

So `params[:year]` is assigned to `@year`, and second part of expression is not assigned to anything. You should use explicit brackets if you want to use or:

```
@year = (params[:year] or Time.now.year)
```

And this is the difference.