# Counting total sum of each value in one column w.r.t another in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing

I have tab delimited data with multiple columns.

I have OS names in column 31 and data bytes in columns 6 and 7. What I want to do is count the total volume of each unique OS.

So, I did something in Perl like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

my @hhfilelist  = glob "*.txt";
my %count = ();

for my $f (@hhfilelist) {
    open F, $f || die "Cannot open $f: $!";
    while (<F>) {
        chomp;
        my @line = split /\t/;
        # counting volumes in col 6 and 7 for 31
        $count{$line[30]} = $line[5] + $line[6];     
    }
    close (F);
}

my $w = 0;

foreach $w (sort keys %count) {
    print "$w\t$count{$w}\n";
}
```

So, the result would be something like

```
Windows    100000
Linux        5000
Mac OSX     15000
Android      2000
```

But there seems to be some error in this code because the resulting values I get aren't as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd consider up-voting your question (on style, not the bug itself) if you actually provided sample input causing the problem, actual output and expected output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you're not actually ADDING up the counts - you overwrite the last count for any OS with the count from the last line for that OS.

```
$count{$line[30]} = $line[5] + $line[6];
```

Should be

```
$count{$line[30]} += $line[5] + $line[6];
```

As additional considerations that can improve your code overall but don't affect the correctness of it:

1. Please use 3-argument form of open and Lexical filehandles:

   ```
    open(my $filehandle, "<", $f) || die "Cannot open $f: $!";
   ```
2. If you're 100% sure you file doesn't contain quoted field values or tabs in the field contents, your `split` based logic is OK. For really complicated X-separated files, I would strongly recommend using `Text::CSV_XS`/`Text::CSV` CPAN module
3. Don't need to initialize `%count` or `$w` variables - hash will get autoinitialized to empty hash, and `$w` gets assigned to as loop variable - you may want to actually declare it in the loop itself: `foreach my $w (sort keys %count) {`
4. Please don't use 1-letter variables. `$w` is meaningless in the last loop, whereas `$os_name` is clear.

Comment: well that was embarrassing. such an elementary mistake :). thanks for the advice.

Comment: @sfactor - if that's the most embarassing bug you ever make, consider yourself lucky :)   I had much worse

Answer (score 3):

Your expression

```
open F, $f || die "Cannot open $f: $!";
```

has a subtle bug in it that will eventually bite you, though probably not today.

The `||` operator has higher precedence than the comma-operator to its left and so this expression actually gets parsed as

```
open F, ($f || die "Cannot open $f: $!")
```

which is to say, you will `die` when `$f` has a false (0, `""`, or `undef`) value, not when the `open` statement fails to open the file with the name given by `$f`.

To do what you mean, you could either use parentheses:

```
open (F, $f) || die ...
```

or use the alternate low-precedence `or` operator

```
open F, $f  or  die ...
```

([At times I have been bitten by this myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512547/what-is-the-difference-between-perls-or-and-and-short-circuit-op))

Answer (score 2):

```
$count{$line[30]} = $line[5] + $line[6];
```

should use the += operator to add the row's sum *to* the total, rather than set it *as* the total:

```
$count{$line[30]} += $line[5] + $line[6];
```

Comment: TFGITW? The First Good and Interesting Tangle of Words?