# I want to sort array of arrays in Perl, but the result is not sorted

Tags: perl, sorting

I have an array of arrays that I want to sort. Each element of array A is an array with 3 elements.
Array A looks like:

```
my @A = ([2,3,1], [1,2,3], [1,0,2], [3,1,2], [2,2,4]);
```

I want to sort A in ascending order. When comparing 2 elements, the first number is used. If there is a tie, the second number is used, and then the third number.

Here is my code. I use a function 'cmpfunc' to compare 2 elements.

```
sub cmpfunc {
    return ($a->[0] <=> $b->[0]) or 
           ($a->[1] <=> $b->[1]) or
           ($a->[2] <=> $b->[2]);
}
my @B = sort cmpfunc @A;
print "Result:\n";
for my $element (@B) {
    print join(",", @{$element}) . "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
1,2,3
1,0,2
2,3,1
2,2,4
3,1,2
```

The result is somewhat sorted, but not correct. What I expect is:

```
1,0,2
1,2,3
2,2,4
2,3,1
3,1,2
```

Is there any error in my comparison function?
The strange thing is, when I put the comparison code in block, the result is correctly sorted.

```
my @C = sort { ($a->[0] <=> $b->[0]) or 
               ($a->[1] <=> $b->[1]) or
               ($a->[2] <=> $b->[2]) } @A;
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512547

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are executing

```
return ($a->[0] <=> $b->[0])
```

which returns before it gets to any of the "or" clauses.

Either remove the "return" keyword, or add parenthesis around the *entire* arg list for return:

```
sub cmpfunc {
    return(($a->[0] <=> $b->[0]) or
           ($a->[1] <=> $b->[1]) or
           ($a->[2] <=> $b->[2]));
}
```

Comment: *OR* use the tighter-binding or: `||`.

Answer (score 11):

The reason you observe this "wrong" behavior is the priority of `or` operator, the lowest possible. In this situation it means that

```
return ($a->[0] <=> $b->[0]) or 
       ($a->[1] <=> $b->[1]) or
       ($a->[2] <=> $b->[2]);
```

is interpreted as OR-ing

```
return ($a->[0] <=> $b->[0])
```

and the rest of the line -- nonsense in this case, as return never returns. :)

So you should use C's OR:

```
return ($a->[0] <=> $b->[0]) || 
       ($a->[1] <=> $b->[1]) ||
       ($a->[2] <=> $b->[2]);
```

Answer (score 7):

Needs more parentheses:

```
sub cmpfunc {
    return (($a->[0] <=> $b->[0]) or
            ($a->[1] <=> $b->[1]) or
            ($a->[2] <=> $b->[2]));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    sub cmpfunc {
    return ($a->[0] <=> $b->[0]) or 
           ($a->[1] <=> $b->[1]) or
           ($a->[2] <=> $b->[2]);
}
```

you can delete 'return' here.

```
    sub cmpfunc {
     ($a->[0] <=> $b->[0]) or 
     ($a->[1] <=> $b->[1]) or
     ($a->[2] <=> $b->[2]);
}
```

Comment: It will still return the first statement that evaluates true.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera It is supposed to do that.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution to Daniel's:

```
sub cmpfunc {
    return ($a->[0] <=> $b->[0]) ||
           ($a->[1] <=> $b->[1]) ||
           ($a->[2] <=> $b->[2]);
}
```

The problem with `or` this case is that it has lower precedence than assignment, so your function only returns the result of `($a->[0] <=> $b->[0])`, which is -1, 0 or 1 if the left hand side is numerically lower than, equal to or larger than the right hand side respectively. `||` has higher precedence, so the entire boolean expression is evaluated before returning. As mentioned, you can wrap the expression in parentheses if you prefer that to `||`. I personally don't.

Comment: Actually, it returns only the first comparison, no matter what it returns. Try `sub a { return 0 or die "Ough" }`.