# LogicalOperators : When do we use operator OR and when do we use ||

Tags: perl

I am working on a small script using Perl and i am confused which logical operator has to be used for comparing strings

Sample Code :

```
if (($app eq "appname1")OR($app eq "appname2")OR($app eq "appname3"))
```

Do i have to use `OR` (or) `||`

Comment: They are the same, except that `or` has much lower precedence. See [about it in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-or-and-Exclusive-Or). This does imply differences in use, but in your example you can use either. Also, find the precedence table in the same page.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512547/what-is-the-difference-between-perls-or-and-and-short-circuit-o, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136583/what-is-the-difference-between-and-or-in-perl

Answer (score 6):

The general rule of thumb tends to be:

- Use `||` to combine boolean operations, such as `if ($app eq "appname1" || $app eq "appname2" || $app eq "appname3") { ... }`
- Use `or` for flow control, such as `open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Open failed: $!"`
- Use parentheses when in doubt or if you think the resulting structure might be unclear to a reader (including yourself in six months)

Answer (score 4):

In this case, it doesn't matter, because:

1. You're using parentheses, which have the highest precedence
2. `eq` has a higher precedence than both `||` and `or`

Here's what [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-or-and-Exclusive-Or) says:

> Binary "`or`" returns the logical disjunction of the two surrounding
>   expressions. It's equivalent to `||` except for the very low
>   precedence.

Also note that `OR` (uppercase) is not a valid Perl operator, but `or` (lowercase) is.

Comment: Ohk Thanks Matt.. Sorry I didn't mean to use  uppercase OR actually i was trying to highlight it in my question